# How to integrate: $\int^{\infty}_{0} \exp(i\lambda t)dt$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis

I found a integral in Schwinger's *classical electrodynamics*, p. 396. Does anyone know, how to perform this?
$$\int^{\infty}_{0} \exp(i\lambda t)dt=\dfrac{i}{\lambda}$$

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: What is $\lambda$?

Comment: what is the condition on $\lambda$?

Comment: I think $\lambda$ must be complex in this case?

Comment: $\lambda$ is real and larger than $0$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let us give to $\lambda$ a small positive imaginary part $\lambda\mapsto\lambda+i\mu$, for $\mu>0$. Then we need to calculate
$$
\int_0^\infty e^{-(\mu-i\lambda)x}dx\,.
$$
This integral is now convergent and can be evaluated directly
$$
\int_0^\infty e^{-(\mu-i\lambda)x}dx = -\frac{e^{-(\mu-i\lambda)x}}{\mu-i\lambda}\Big|_0^\infty=\frac{1}{\mu-i\lambda}\,,
$$
where we have used that the exponential is now decaying to zero at infinity.
As $\mu\to0^+$, the right-hand side tends to 
$$
\frac{i}{\lambda}\,,
$$
while the left-hand side formally gives back the original integral.
This procedure for making this kind of oscillatory integrals finite  essentially amount to an analytic continuation in $\lambda$.

Comment: Thank you! May I ask how to perform $\int^{\infty}_{0}\exp^{-(\mu-i\lambda)x}dx$?

Comment: @Yikai I added an intermediate step that should clarify this, let me know!

Comment: Thank you very much. I can understand it.